# Explanation of SolrNet connection

Tags: c#, solrnet

Why is the container of the SolrNet connections kept static? This is a very big fault, as when, in our application, we send an asynchronous request to our application, SolrNet behaves abnormally. How I can avoid this issue in SolrNet?

```
class P
{
    static void M(string[] a)
    { 
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            f1();
        });
        Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            f2();
        });

        t.Start();
        t1.Start();
        t.Join();
        t1.Join();
    }

    static void f1()
    {
        Startup.Init<Doc>(new SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr3/"));
        ISolrOperations<Doc> solrOperations2 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
    }

    static void f2()
    {
        Startup.Init<Doc>(new SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr1/"));
        ISolrOperations<Doc> solrOperations2 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error or abnormal behavior you see?

Comment: In my application, I have multiple solr indexes let say 5, and I have 5 separate classes that represents one solr document. now abnormal behavior is when In one particular case I send asynchronous request to application where it gives error key already exist in container.

Comment: can you post a failing test, or at least the full stack trace?

Comment: at SolrNet.Utils.Container.Register(String key, Type serviceType, Converter`2 factory) in D:\solrNet\SolrNet\Utils\Container.cs:line 83
at SolrNet.Utils.Container.Register[T](String key, Converter`2 factory) in D:\solrNet\SolrNet\Utils\Container.cs:line 71
at SolrNet.Startup.Init[T](ISolrConnection connection) in D:\solrNet\SolrNet\Startup.cs:line 98
at EntryPoint.Program.funa() in D:\solrNet\EntryPoint\Program.cs:line 51
at EntryPoint.Program.<Main>b__1() in D:\solrNet\EntryPoint\Program.cs:line 31
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run

Comment: can you post your Program.cs or at least the offending part?

Comment: or more specifically, where are you calling Startup.Init are where are you calling the method that calls Startup.Init?

Comment: This was just for reference! as you can think of it if container is static that is being shared at appDomain level then let say two asynchronous requests came and both can assume that connection is not initiated yet and both can go initializing connection in parallel there u can find the problem

Comment: @MauricioScheffer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1845/discussion-between-ahsan-iqbal-and-mauricio-scheffer)

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have the time to chat. Please post a failing test or the offending code, otherwise I can't help you. I think you're using SolrNet incorrectly, but I can't say for sure until I see some code.

Comment: class P
{
static void M(string[] a)
{
Thread t=new Thread(delegate()
{
f1();
});
Thread t1=new Thread(delegate()
{
f2();
});
t.Start();
t1.Start();
t.Join();
t1.Join();
}
static void f1()
{
Startup.Init<Doc>(new SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr3/"));
ISolrOperations<Doc> solrOperations2 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
}
static void f2()
{
Startup.Init<Doc>(new SolrNet.Impl.SolrPostConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr1/"));
ISolrOperations<Doc> solrOperations2 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Document>>();
}
}

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not as a comment, so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As [explained in the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess#With_built-in_container), the built-in container (Startup) is currently limited to access multiple cores/instances with different mapped types. If you want more flexibility about this, either switch to Windsor / StructureMap / Autofac, or [help implement this 
   feature](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=83).
2. Registrations in the built-in container may not be thread-safe as you have discovered, but you gain nothing by registering / initializing SolrNet in different threads. Just move all initialization to a single thread, the actual heavy work is performed when you do solr.Query(...) or solr.Add(...) which *is* thread-safe.

Comment: at which version of solrnet Windsor / StructureMap / Autofac are available

Comment: Windsor and StructureMap are available in 0.3.1. Autofac in 0.4.0a1

Comment: One more thing weather "Windsor / StructureMap" are thread safe?

Comment: @Ahsan Iqbal: Windsor is thread-safe, both in registration and resolution. All containers are thread-safe in resolution.

Comment: thanx alot for your help one more thing please is it possible to implement a functionality in SolrNetFacility so that it could use POST method rather than GET as i often need to send very large number of parameters to solr that exceeds url limit.

Comment: @Ahsan Iqbal: if you have further questions about SolrNet or Windsor please create new questions.