# SolrNet - Multiple Instances with Custom Connection

Tags: c#, solr, castle-windsor, castle, solrnet

I am using Solr.NET within my application. Within the application, I need to connect to two different solr servers. Both of these solr servers return the same type of document, let's call the document type Foo.

Also, I need to use a custom connection so that all queries are always POSTed to solr.

Here is what I have so far:

```
StartUp.Init<Foo>(new PostOnlyConnection(connectionString1))
StartUp.Init<Foo>(new PostOnlyConnection(connectionString2))
```

Obviously, the IoC container throws an error on this since the two types are the same. I tried to resolve this issue with the information located in [this article](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess#With_Windsor_facility), but the Windsor facility does not allow me to pass in a custom connection object, just the connection string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're still using the built in container (Startup) which is limited to different document types. The [article](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess#With_Windsor_facility) you posted contains an example for Windsor.

I am not too familiar with Windsor but you should be able to reregister `ISolrConnection` with your custom `PostOnlyConnection`.

References:

[Explaination of SolrNet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830623/question-about-solrnet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

If the Windsor option is not working, you could create 2 classes that inherits from the same class just to init a solr connection with a different type.

```
class Foo {}
class FooA : Foo {}
class FooB : Foo {}

StartUp.Init<FooA>(new PostOnlyConnection(connectionString1))
StartUp.Init<FooB>(new PostOnlyConnection(connectionString2))
```

I have more than 1 core and this is the solution I use. It creates some challenges, meaning that you will need some template methods to query data in each solr instance.